# Mongodb collection does not search with multiple search

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi,  I am getting a problem while dealing with search on multiple fields. I have a collection with over 1 million records. When I perform operation on single field, it gives result in a flash. But when I try with multiple fields, it goest to toss. I am trying to search with the criteria matching as below : first name starts with 'b', last name ends with 'on' and email exact matches with "bwashington@zoombeat.net".

My collection looks something like :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5391c81069f6872810004e49"),
    "salutation": "frau",
    "date_of_birth": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.0Z"),
    "first_name": {
        "0": {
            "value": "Benjamin",
            "date_inserted": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
            "date_modified": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
            "sweepstake": {
                "sweepstake_id": "535e03888a06f83c12001380",
                "sweepstake_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/redlemon\/sweepstakes\/register_user\/1\/53563bd68a06f8941300002b",
                "date_inserted": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
                "date_modified": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
                "current_page": "1",
                "session_id": "4ef315c35b5a1162eedc37fa109c3c57",
                "last_activity": ISODate("2014-06-06T13:45:31.0Z")
            }
        }
    },
    "last_name": {
        "0": {
            "value": "Washington",
            "date_inserted": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
            "date_modified": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
            "sweepstake": {
                "sweepstake_id": "535e03888a06f83c12001380",
                "sweepstake_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/redlemon\/sweepstakes\/register_user\/1\/53563bd68a06f8941300002b",
                "date_inserted": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
                "date_modified": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
                "current_page": "1",
                "session_id": "4ef315c35b5a1162eedc37fa109c3c57",
                "last_activity": ISODate("2014-06-06T13:45:31.0Z")
            }
        }
    },
    "email": {
        "0": {
            "date_inserted": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
            "date_modified": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
            "sweepstake": {
                "sweepstake_id": "535e03888a06f83c12001380",
                "sweepstake_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/redlemon\/sweepstakes\/register_user\/1\/53563bd68a06f8941300002b",
                "date_inserted": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
                "date_modified": "2014-06-06 03:54:24",
                "current_page": "1",
                "session_id": "4ef315c35b5a1162eedc37fa109c3c57",
                "last_activity": ISODate("2014-06-06T13:45:31.0Z")
            },
            "email_id": "bwashington@zoombeat.net",
            "email_optin_flag": "1",
            "single_optin_flag": "1",
            "double_optin_flag": "0",
            "current_status": "active",
            "suspicious_flag": NumberInt(0)
        }
    },
    "last_inserted_date": ISODate("2014-06-06T13:54:24.0Z"),
    "last_date_modified": ISODate("2014-06-06T13:54:24.0Z")
}
```

I have added index on the 'leads' collection as :

```
db.leads.ensureIndex({first_name:1},{sparse:true});
db.leads.ensureIndex({"last_name":1}); 
db.leads.ensureIndex({“email”:1});
db.leads.ensureIndex({"first_name.value":1}); 
db.leads.ensureIndex({"last_name.value":1});
db.leads.ensureIndex({"email.email_id":1});
```

When I check query in mongodb shell with currentOp(), it looks like :

```
"query" : {
    "$query" : {
        "first_name.value" : /^b/i,
        "last_name.value" : /on$/i,
        "email.email_id" : /^bwashington@zoombeat.net$/i 
    },   
    "$orderby" : { "last_inserted_date" : NumberLong(-1) } 
}
```

Comment: From the index documentation :

Every query, including update operations, uses one and only one index.

In other words, MongoDB doesn't support index intersection . Thus, creating a huge number of indexes is pointless unless there are queries that use this index and this index only. Also, make sure you're calling the correct Count() method here. If you call the linq-to-object extensions (IEnumerable's Count() extension rather than MongoCursor's Count, it will actually have to fetch and hydrate all objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your query is slower when you're searching by multiple fields is that MongoDB is not using indexes (efficiently) for your query.

In version 2.6 MongoDB got a new feature called [index intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) which can use intersection of multiple indexes to fulfill query. Although that feature can be useful, using a compound index you'll get better results.

You can additionally optimize your query by removing regex search on e-mail and do a simple equality check, which is faster than regex:

```
{
    "email.email_id" : "bwashington@zoombeat.net",
    "first_name.value" : /^b/i,
    "last_name.value" : /on$/i

}
```

You can create a compound index:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({
    "email.email_id" : 1, 
    "first_name.value": 1,
    "last_name.value" : 1,
    "last_inserted_date" : -1
});
```

The `last_inserted_date` date is in the index so that MongoDB can use it when sorting (if your sorting operation consumes more than 32MB you will get an error). Check the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) for more details about using indexing when sorting data.

**Edit**

I didn't see the proper structure of your document because of the bad formatting :) Adding indexes didn't work because you can't add an index on two arrays.

Your `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` fields are basically arrays, but you should convert them into embedded documents.

```
"first_name": {
    ...
},
"last_name": {
    ...
},
"email": {
    ...
}
```

**Edit 2:**

As you can't convert your data structure, your have reduced options. You can't create a compound index on multiple array fields. To troubleshoot this problem better you should use [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) command (possibly while using [hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/)) to see which index will perform faster.

Comment: Than you so much Christian P. Your suggestion regarding simple equality check is sound helpful. But while adding compound indexes I am getting below error. Appreciate if you can suggest some solution.  db.leads.ensureIndex({"email.email_id" : 1, "first_name.value" : 1, "last_name.value" : 1, "last_inserted_date" : -1});
{
 "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
 "numIndexesBefore" : 37,
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "cannot index parallel arrays [first_name] [email]",
 "code" : 10088
}

Comment: Thank you once again for your reply. My fault for missing this information about structure. My requirement is that I can save multiple values for the fields as : { first_name{ "0":{}, "1":{}}, last_name{ "0":{}, "1" : {}}, email{ "0":{}, "1":{}} }. Is it possible to add compound index with this structure? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, you can't create a compound index on two or more arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think Christian P. gave the best answer. Compound indexes will help your query a LOT.

Just one more thing you should consider, What information are you looking for in your query?

Maybe you can try aggregation framework with project if you only need a few fields that can cut the size of the query.

And if you need to have so many indexes use index hint on your query to ensure you are using the best one.